# Calling property setter within lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, properties

I have a class using the property decorator for setter/getter of a variable.

```
class Application:

    @property
    def volume(self):
        return self._volume

    @volume.setter
    def volume(self, value):
        self._volume = value
```

I want to be able to set the volume of an application within a lambda.

Lambdas do not allow for statements, only expressions, so it is not as easy as just calling `lambda application, value: application.volume = value`.

```
# Things I have tried and have not worked
lambda application, value: application.volume = value    # Can't assign values in lambda
lambda application, value: application.volume(value)     # Getter is run and turned into a callable
lambda application, value: (application.volume := value) # Assignment expression can not resolve application
```

What I have been able to do, is change the way of defining the property

```
class Application:

    def get_volume(self):
        return self._volume

    def set_volume(self, value):
        self._volume = value

    volume = property(get_volume, set_volume)
```

Which then allows me to call the setter function directly

```
lambda application, value: application.set_volume(value)
```

This solution ignores the point of properties though. Is there a way of calling the setter within a lambda while still using the property decorator tags, or is the hack-y ignore the property and use the setter directly the best way to set the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setattr`:

```
class Application:

    @property
    def volume(self):
        print(f"volume get")
        return self._volume

    @volume.setter
    def volume(self, value):
        print(f"volume set {value}")
        self._volume = value

update_volume = lambda application, value: setattr(application, "volume", value)
x = Application()
update_volume(x, 5)
print(x.volume)
```

Prints:

```
volume set 5
volume get
5
```